# Creating a Batch to go through all folders on a share and move files

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, scripting, directory, conditional-statements

Here is what I am attempting to do and if I can get your help it would be greatly appreciated!

Issue:
I want to create a script to do the following:

1. Go out to a network share where all account folders exist (2,400 folders with a 9-digit naming convention for account numbers, i.e folder name is `123456789`).
2. Then go through a specific directory within the account folders that have a `time stamp` naming convention (i.e 123456789\Jan_29_2013_453pm).
3. Next, all folder structures are the same for all account folders EXCEPT the time stamped folder under the root (i.e 123456789`Jan_29_2013_453pm`\data).
4. Once being able to get through the time stamp folder there will be a set of folders that start off with a naming convention of media1, media2, media3, media4, media5, etc. that I need to access in order to move files.
5. I need to move a certain file from all `media` folders into media1. **There is an unknown amount of media folders for different account folders. Some may have 1 and other may have 50.
6. I need to run a test within the data folder (123456789\Jan_29_2013_453pm\data) to open a logfile.txt to see if a specific string exists at the end of the log (i.e item was successfully created as well as item has failed`).
7. If there is a SUCCESSFUL string in the logfile.txt, then go ahead and move all files from other media folders into media1. If a FAILURE string, then output the account folder name to a log file (output.txt) so I am aware which account folders failed (I would append the output as I will run this script multiple times).

The idea is to disregard account folders that have just a single media1 folder. Other account directories that have more than ONE media folder need to run a test against the log for SUCCESS or FAIL and depending on the string, to move a single file from all other `media` (media2,media3,media4,etc.) folders over to media1 unless FAILURE is read in the log.

I created a text file with all account folders on the share. I'm sure a FOR statement can be used against it. I'm also sure that a FOR statement can be used to go through the log in the "DATA" directory to look for the "SUCCESSFUL" or "FAILED" string.

The hard part I see is being able to get through the time stamped folder in order to get to the DATA directory.

THANKS AGAIN FOR ALL THE HELP!

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:beginning
echo.
echo.
echo ===========================================================
echo Starting on !date! !time! on !Computername!
echo ===========================================================
echo.
echo Press ENTER to begin...
pause
echo.

goto :main

:main

cls
echo.
set /P acct=Please type the 9 digit account number you would like to restore: 
set acctDir=X:\!acct!\
set acctDir2=media1\Setup\setup.exe /cd
set acctDir3=media1
set x=x:\!acct!\!userDir!
set sumLog="x:\!acct!\!userDir!\SummaryLog.txt"
set succ=finished
set log=c:\logs.txt


    echo. Starting on !date! !time! on !Computername! >> !log!
    echo.
    echo The account number you selected is: !acct!
    echo.

    goto :user

:user

    set /p answer=Is this correct (Y/N)? 
    echo.

    if /i !answer!==y goto :yes (
    ) else ( 
        echo.
        echo Ok. Let's try again^^!
        echo.
        pause
        cls
        goto :main
        )
    )

:yes

    set c=0
    For /f %%a in ('dir !acctDir! /B /A:D') do (
    set /a c+=1
    echo !c!    %%a
    set dir!c!=%%a
    )

    echo. 
    set /p userIn="Select a directory [1-!c!]: "
    set userDir=!dir%userIn%!

    echo.
    echo You selected !userDir! for your data retrieval.
    echo.
    goto :execute

:execute

    echo.
    echo The software will now be installed...
    start !acctdir!\!userDir!\!acctDir2! >>!log!

:move

    forfiles /p "!acctdir!\!userDir!\" /s /m *.ARC /c "cmd /c move @file !acctdir!\!userDir!\!acctdir3!"

    goto

:string

    findstr " .*!succ!" !sumLog!
    if exist errorlevel 0 (
        pause
        goto :move
    ) else (
        goto :eof
    )

endlocal
goto :eof
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve this on your own? If so, please post relevant code that you have written. As well as what, specifically, you're having trouble with.

Comment: I submitted what I have, so basically what I would like to do after the setup.exe is kicked off is to move over those files from what I was asking above. I'll admit, I'm still trying to get better with FOR statements. They're hard to grasp but once I do I'm sure I'll do much better.

Comment: Actually, what I am asking could take place at the beginning or end of the script. Does not really matter. I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: I was thinking another sub routine could be used within `:main` to make this happen since all of the variables are already assigned. Actually, create another variable with just \\IP\Share\!acct!\!userdir! then run a FOR statement on this location since the media folder and log files exist in that location. The Account_Files.txt also exist in the Root of the shar \\IP\Share

Comment: Ok, I update my variable and code, for some reason when it goes to parse through the SummaryLog.txt it's not adding `!userDir!` in the path... I dont get it. I can add the path in a CMD and it works perfectly for parsing. Any suggestions? Also, how can I get all *.ARC files in that directory and all subdirectories to move to the media1 folder based on the success of that string? The error returned for parsing is `FINDSTR: Cannot open x:\101004357\\SummaryLog.txt` The path is missing the user input from !userDir! even though the variable is in the code??????

Comment: Provide details.  `some folder, certain string` don't make it easy to follow.  Also show folder structure in a text block as you get from `dir /b /s /a-d`

Comment: So.. here is the structure of the directory `X:\123456789\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM` the second directory is user input from what the user selected to access as there are multiple time stamped directories. Which is why the timestamped directory is a variable as !userDir! This would be used in the path as that second directory where the SummaryLog.txt exists.

Comment: C:\>dir X:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\ /b /A:D output=
    `archives
    Media1
    Media2
    Media3` I don't see any files with output, but that shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: Community.... Please keep in mind that I'm only asking because I really want to learn. Any suggestions or help would be more than appreciated. I feel like Im really really close to completing what I need to do. Thanks again!

Comment: Anyone interested in helping me out this morning? This has been bugging the crap out of me.

Comment: I guess I should give up here as nobody seems too interested in helping?

Comment: in the `:move` section there is a `goto` without a label specified...